# How to change the visibility from a stackpanel in a splitview from another class

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to change the visibility from a stackpanel from visibility.Collapsed to visibility.visible. But I can't do it in the mainpage where it is located. That is because you need to be logged in in the application so I want to do it in the Homepage.cs but how can i change the value of a stackpanel from there ? I need to do it that way because all my views are loaded in the frame that you can see below in the code.

Below you find the code of the splitview

```
<SplitView x:Name="mySplitView" IsPaneOpen="False" DisplayMode="CompactInline">
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <StackPanel Background="Gray" Tapped="StackPanel_Tapped">
            <Button FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;" Click="Menu_Button_Click" Width="50" Height="50"  />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Tapped="Home_StackPanel_Tapped">
                <Button FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE80F;" Width="50" Height="50" />
                <TextBlock Text="Home" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Line X1="0" X2="0" Y1="5" Y2="5" StrokeThickness="1.5" Stretch="UniformToFill" Height="10" />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Tapped="Company_StackPanel_Tapped" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <Button FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE731;" Width="50" Height="50"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Bedrijven" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Tapped="Event_StackPanel_Tapped" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <Button FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE787;" Width="50" Height="50"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Evenementen" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Tapped="Promo_StackPanel_Tapped" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <Button FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE8EC;" Width="50" Height="50" />
                <TextBlock Text="Promoties" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Line X1="0" X2="0" Y1="5" Y2="5" StrokeThickness="1.5" Stretch="UniformToFill" Height="10"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Tapped="Login_StackPanel_Tapped">
                <Button FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE77B;" Width="50" Height="50" />
                <TextBlock Text="Inloggen" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Tapped="Registreer_StackPanel_Tapped" >
                <Button FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE8FA;" Width="50" Height="50" />
                <TextBlock Text="Registreren" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="profielwijzigen" Tapped="Profiel_Wijzigen_StackPanel_Tapped" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <Button FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE713;" Width="50" Height="50" />
                <TextBlock Text="Profiel Wijzigen" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </SplitView.Pane>
    <SplitView.Content>
        <Frame Name="mainFrame">
            Wait for redirect
        </Frame>
    </SplitView.Content>
</SplitView>
```

Comment: You should look into binding - in your code behind you should bind to some property that encapsulates the log in state or whatever it is that determines the visibility of the stackpanel.

Comment: You can start using a bit of MVVM. Then certain VM just need a property to be bound for two: one to set and other to read and change visibility (either by data trigger or with converter). If you want view-only solution, then you can to use common `RelativeSource AncestorType` parent and use one of its properties (`Tag`? if that doesn't work, custom attached property will). In one project I've created a custom panel class `public class MyGrid: Grid { }` for some complex layouting of nested user controls.

Comment: Just checked, `RelativeSource` won't work from within `Frame.Content`. You have to use proxy or better - use MVVM approach.

Comment: Just one of the many reasons NOT to use frames and pages. You should use a contentcontrol and usercontrols in that.

Answer (score 1):

Such tasks are very easy if you start using MVVM. Below is an example (as a kind of introduction).

For each different View (`UserControl`, data template, window, etc.) you have to create a view model (VM). View models can have complex relationship. Let's create one:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string property = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));


    bool _show;
    public bool Show
    {
        get { return _show; }
        set
        {
            _show = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Typically there would be more properties and they would be dedicated to handle a specific view (e.g. everything in main window or certain user control), but for the moment lets keep it simple.

Next lets recreate your issue: we will have `StackPanel` and `Frame`. The frame part will have `CheckBox` used to change visibility by binding to a bool property. And `StackPanel` will have some text (to see if it works) and binding of visibility to same bool property.

```
<Window ... >
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="converter"/>
        <local:ViewModel x:Key="vm"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding Show, Converter={StaticResource converter}}" DataContext="{StaticResource vm}">
            <TextBlock Text="Some test"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Frame>
            <Frame.Content>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Show}" DataContext="{StaticResource vm}"/>
            </Frame.Content>
        </Frame>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The whole idea of MVVM is to utilize `DataContext` inheritance: any nested framework element will be taken context from its parent. But in this example it is set directly for each.

The instance of view model is created within windows resource. You may need one on application level and maybe even passing it around (not sure how your frame content looks like).

Converter is used to convert `bool` to `Visibility`.

If you run it you should see something like:

[image]

Comment: This is working but my problem is is that i wan't to change the visibility value in another class that is not the class of that xaml but from another xaml and i don't know how to do that

Answer (score -2):

You could use some **events**.

In the sub-component used for the login (say class is `LoginControl`) you declare the event:

```
public event EventHandler LoggedIn = delegate {};
```

You register an handler in the main component:

```
loginControl.LoggedIn += (s, e) => {
    Company_StackPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    Event_StackPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    Promo_StackPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
};
```

In your `LoginControl` when the user has logged-in you raise the event:

```
this.LoggedIn(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```